# How to return the remote database name which is calling a stored proc in a different database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a number of different databases on a single SQL Server 2008 R2. For arguments sake, let's call them DB_A, DB_B, and DB_C. I've been asked to develop as stored proc that will live on DB_A. This stored proc will be used to drop and create indexes, and also store some extra information about the index in a table on DB_A. When this stored proc is called from DB_C or DB_C, it will be able to drop and create indexes on the calling database, but store the extra information about the index in the table on DB_A.

Here's what I would like to do: I would like the stored proc to be able to get the name of the calling database WITHOUT having to request the database name as a parameter.

Here is a simple example:

```
USE [DB_A]

CREATE PROC sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom
AS 
BEGIN
      DECLARE @calling_db NVARCHAR(128)
      SET @calling_db = DB_NAME()
      PRINT 'calling database: ' + @calling_db
END
```

When I execute the stored procedure in DB_A ...

```
EXEC sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom
```

...it returns: "**calling database: DB_A**"

When I execute the stored procedure in DB_B ...

```
USE DB_B
GO

EXEC DB_A.dbo.sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom
```

...it returns: "**calling database: DB_A**".

After reading up on various SQL Server Metadata Functions, this is exactly what it should do. But what I would like is to change the code so that it sets @calling_db to the name of calling database, so that my example stored proc would print: "**calling database: DB_B**".

Unfortunately, I can't find any Metadata Functions that can do this. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Very interesting question. Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you don't want to have the process that calls the sproc provide the dbname as a parameter (other than having to support a parameter and provide it)? One thought if there isn't a direct way to do this would be to make the parameter optional @CallingDB NVARCHAR(128) = NULL and check if the value is null. If so, default to use DB_NAME(). Of course, this means the invocation from other databases would need to provide the name...

Comment: The only real reason I don't want to use a parameter is I think that there must be a way to do it, and I hate walking away from a challenge like this without finding a solution.

Comment: FYI, the same question was [asked on the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/db-id-context-from-farther-up-call-stack), although it hasn't been answered. The suggestions made were to use extended events, SQL CLR or maintain your own call stack using [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx).

Comment: Not sure it this will help or not.  But if you prefix your stored procedure name with “sp_” and put it in the master database db_name() will return the name of the database the stored procedure was called from.  When you call the stored procedure don’t call it with the database name (i.e. exec  master.. sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom) just call exec sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom .

Answer (score 4):

To make SP run in the context of current connection you need create your SP on `master` database *and* make it a system object.

```
USE MASTER 
GO 

CREATE PROC sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom
AS 
BEGIN
      DECLARE @calling_db NVARCHAR(128)
      SET @calling_db = DB_NAME()
      PRINT 'calling database: ' + @calling_db
END
GO

EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom'
GO
```

Check how it works:

```
USE [DB_A]
GO

EXEC sp_WhatDatabaseAmICallingFrom
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is quite old but I found something that at least helped me.

If you are using DB_A and are calling an stored procedure in DB_B like:

```
USE DB_A
EXEC db_b.dbo.sproc
```

The only way I have found to get the "calling database" id is to run a select against sys.dm_tran_locks inside the stored procedure. request_session_id should be your spid, resource_type should be DATABASE and request_owner_type should be SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE. Such a shared lock always exist on a database for each connected session. The query would be something like:

```
SELECT resource_database_id FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID and resource_type = 'DATABASE' and request_owner_type = 'SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE'
```

Although this requires the executing user to have at least VIEW SERVER STATE permissions on the server. In my case that was not a problem though..

Comment: The problem with this is that your SELECT, as given, returns **2** rows; one for the calling database-catalog, and one for the database-catalog where the sproc is defined. You'd need to add "AND DB_ID() != resource_database_id" to your SELECT.  (Additionally, this approach works great from a _function_.)

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Mike's answer, this is an example of a solution that works in Sql2012.

You must create the function while logged in as a user with sufficient permissions ('VIEW SERVER STATE'), but those who use the function only need permission to execute the function itself.

```
USE [DB_A];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCallingDbCatName()
RETURNS nvarchar(128) 
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(128);
    SELECT TOP 1 @result = DB_NAME(resource_database_id) 
        FROM sys.dm_tran_locks 
        WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID 
            AND resource_type = 'DATABASE' 
            AND request_owner_type = 'SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE' 
        ORDER BY IIF(resource_database_id != DB_ID(), 0, 1);
    RETURN @result;
END
GO

USE [DB_A];
SELECT DB_A.dbo.GetCallingDbCatName(); --"DB_A"
USE [DB_B];
SELECT DB_A.dbo.GetCallingDbCatName(); --"DB_B"
USE [DB_C];
SELECT DB_A.dbo.GetCallingDbCatName(); --"DB_C"
```

And from there, you should be able to build the actual functionality you need without needing to pollute the *master* dbcat.

**EDIT 2019-07-26** - FYI: This works because **every** connection to (or use of) a dbcat other than *master* or *tempdb* will have a SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE lock. [The explanation below is from this page](https://mysqlpages.blogspot.com/2018/03/lock-types.html?m=1)  ( And [another page that explains it similarly](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/definitions-needed-transaction-workspace-latches) )

> The purpose of the SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE lock owner is to
>   prevent SQL Server from acquiring EXCLUSIVE_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE
>   locks, that is, to prevent a process from dropping, restoring, or
>   changing readability status for a database, while the database is in
>   use. The reason SQL Server does not acquire these locks for the master
>   and tempdb databases is that these databases cannot be dropped, or
>   have their readability status changed. In addition, we never restore
>   tempdb, and to restore the master database, we must start the entire
>   server in single-user mode so, again, SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE
>   locks are unnecessary.

So when you call the function that lives in DB_A from DB_B, that query returns 2 rows; one for the use of DB_B where the query is running, and one for the use of DB_A where the function runs/lives. This also means that the above query will not work for more complicated call-stacks (DB_A calls func in DB_B which then calls func in DB_C which tries to determine the caller's dbcat; the ORDER BY won't be able to properly choose between DB_A and DB_B.)

Finally, this solution also works from a CLR method. You must remember to execute the "wrapper" Sql function with sufficient permission to use `db_tran_locks`, and the `SqlFunction` attribute must have "SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read". The "context connection" uses the same SPID as the caller, and it lives in the dbcat where the assembly lives (and consequently where the wrapper-function/sproc lives that exposes the CLR method.)

For reference, here's my test CLR method:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = false, DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read), SqlMethod(OnNullCall = true)]
public static SqlString GetCallingDbcatName()
{
    string sqlResult = "";
    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var sqlCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandText = @"
SELECT TOP 1 DB_NAME(resource_database_id) 
  FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
  WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID
    AND resource_type = 'DATABASE'
    AND request_owner_type = 'SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE'
  ORDER BY IIF(resource_database_id != DB_ID(), 0, 1); ";
        sqlResult = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    return sqlResult;
}
```